# WS2008R2 / W7PRO: Cannot rename folder - folder redirection

Tags: windows-server-2008, folder-redirection

After few months from migrating one of my networks on Active Directory this issue started. A few users are encountering an issue from time to time - they cannot rename folders and files on desktop. The system throws an error saying `the folder or file is already in use`.

- Folder redirection takes place in this scenario (Desktop and My Documents)
- Subnet with user PCs is different from subnet with servers (Cisco ASA5505 Security Plus between - all inspection policies disabled on these interfaces)
- Users are running Windows 7 Professional x86
- Server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The folder or file is probably in use.

You should do some troubleshooting to determine whether it's in use on the local machine or the network, and by what.  You can use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), or even the much simpler [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to determine what's locking the files and folders, once you've determined if it's server-side or client-side.  After that, you can release the locking handle, and hopefully track down why this happening, so you can put a stop to it.